# Firebase sdk with react native unable to see anything

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.djamware.com/post/5bbcd38080aca7466989441b/react-native-firebase-tutorial-build-crud-firestore-app) on RN with Firestore. I've so far only used the Firebase Web SDK installed via

```
npm install firebase -save
```

With the following example code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('sessions');

   this.unsubscribe = null;
   this.state = {
      dataSource: [],
      loading: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

   this.unsubscribe = this.ref.onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate);

  }

   componentWillUnmount() {
      his.unsubscribe();
   }

  onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
     const dataSource = [];
     querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

     const { id, desc, zipcode, timestamp } = doc.data();
       dataSource.push({
         key: doc.id,
         doc,
         desc,
         zipcode,
        timestamp,
      });
    });
    this.setState({
       dataSource,
       loading: false,
    });
 }
```

The above code returns absolutely nothing, even if I put a bogus collection name. Nothing runs, and I put a bunch of console.log statements but still can't see anything. I can't even tell if there is any problems connecting to Firestore.

I have not yet tried react-native-firebase module because I thought I am only doing a simple Firestore query, but at same time I am building my app natively on iOS on a Mac.

Am I supposed to be using the react-native-firebase module?

Comment: Yeah, would recommend using react-native-firebase. From their readme on github: "Although the official Firebase JS SDK will work with React Native; it is mainly built for the web and has a limited feature-set compared to native."

Comment: Thanks, TBH I just need the most basic GET and SET, but if the SDK can't even provide that, obviously it cannot even be used.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo error in your componentWillMount. `componentWillUnmount() {
      his.unsubscribe();
   }`

should be:   `componentWillUnmount() {
      this.unsubscribe();
   }`

Also i recommend react-native-firebase.

Comment: its there, I copied incorrectly, must have overwritten it while trying to format the code for code display. honestly my code is exactly like the tutorial minus a few elements in the doc

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone who found this with similar issues, just want to confirm that the Firebase Web SDK is indeed possible to be used for Firestore. There is no need to use react-native-firebase if your use case is very simple CRUD.

My error was that it was pulling the database content just that my render function was not displaying it.